# oauth2.py issue getting gmail credentials

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail

Am am trying to get my Google gmail credentials:

```
OAUTH_TOKEN = ''  # XXX: Obtained with xoauth.py
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = ''  # XXX: Obtained with xoauth.py
GMAIL_ACCOUNT = ''  # XXX: Your Gmail address - example@gmail.com
```

https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/wiki/OAuth2DotPyRunThrough

I tried using this command:

```
$ python oauth2.py --generate_oauth2_token --client_id=364545978226.apps.googleusercontent.com --client_secret=zNrNsBzOOnQy8_O-8LkofeTR
To authorize token, visit this url and follow the directions:
  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=364545978226.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2F
Enter verification code:
```

When I try to access the URI:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=364545978226.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2F
```

I get an error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In 'oauth2.py' I had to use the 'client_id' and 'client_secret' returned from Google's Gmail application access screen.

[image]